# Unable to install module

Tags: perl

Just wanted to download one module:
`sudo cpan HTTP::SimpleLinkChecker`
but while watching outputs, and error returned.

```
t/200.t ............ Link is http://blogs.perl.org/
t/200.t ............ 1/? Link is https://www.perl.org/
t/200.t ............ ok   
t/403.t ............ Link is http://www.pair.com/comdog/cgi-bin/403.cgi
t/403.t ............ 1/1 
#   Failed test 'Unauthorized code works'
#   at t/403.t line 9.
#          got: '200'
#     expected: '403'
```

But what does mean `Unauthorized code works`? Even if I made it with `sudo` privileges.

And second question, what can tell me those pieces -> `t/200.t` or `t/200.t` in testing? At the end of the dots are some links, but how is it connected together?

Moreover the `cpanm` is recommending me to install with `--force` option, which mean to neglect the tests, but if I do so, what would be the consequences? Would it mean the module is broken? So it can break my own script when using it?

Comment: But why does a siimple installing failed then? I dont know why should any tests failed if the module is proper implemented (And I run the installation as sudo), so where could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`*.t` are the actual test files that Perl runs, and names like Unauthorized code works are individual tests (methods). The output at the end (e.g., "Link is...") is just something the test printed to `stderr`.

The source code for HTTP::SimpleLinkChecker is on [Github](https://github.com/briandfoy/http-simplelinkchecker/), and looking at the tests, the *unit* tests actually try to connect to some server (oh my...). That server is http://www.pair.com/comdog/cgi-bin/403.cgi. When I `wget` that, I also get a 200 OK HTTP code, as your test does, but the test expected a 403, and hence it fails.

Bottom line: report a bug with brian d foy, the maintainer of that Perl module (you can probably use the Github link above).

It's up to you if you want to `--force` to install the module. Forcing means to ignore the failing tests and install anyway. This one is probably just a harmless unit test failure, but I'd be suspicious if other tests fail in different ways.

Comment: So you got the same error. That means the problem is not at my side. And by saying "Bottom line", you are suggesting me to report the bug? Just asking, because that would confirm a problem at the server side.

Comment: It looks like the issue was reported 2 years ago: https://github.com/briandfoy/http-simplelinkchecker/issues

Comment: @Herdsman I'd bump the bug report @toolic has linked to. Maybe it gets fixed if enough people complain about it. In the mean time, I'd either `--force` the install or look for another module that does the same thing, maybe [checklink](https://metacpan.org/pod/checklink) works for you.